# Cannot find Violations plugin in Jenkins Manage Plugins tab

Tags: python, jenkins

I have recently installed and configured Jenkins 1.643 on an AWS instance running Ubuntu 14.04. I'm in the process of configuring a python project and would like to add a few plugins. To install each plugin I navigate to Manage Jenkins -> Manage plugins -> Available and then search for the appropriate one. I however can not find Violations on this page and instead find Violations Columns and Violation Comments to Stash. How can I download [Violations](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Violations)? Do I have to add it manually? I've searched around and no one seems to have this issue. Additionally the github page for Violations does not give the best insight on how to add this package...

Comment: This happened to me too. The provide answer worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have no problem with finding this plugin in my Manage Jenkins panel, but since you do you can download .hpi file from here:
http://mirrors.jenkins-ci.org/plugins/violations/0.7.11/
and go to advenced options http://localhost:8080/jenkins/pluginManager/advanced and send hpi file (upload plugin)